# What other steps beside using usbipd, compiling aravis libs and running arv-viewer-0.8 to access USB3Vision Aravis camera using WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, libusb, aravis

The USB3 camera seems to successfully attach using usbipd per lsusb
However when I run arv-viewer-0.8 the camera is listed, but when selected, the "Start video" acquisition remains grayed out and the settings do not show.
Running the Aravis Viewer in debug mode I get following

```
[10:33:49.568]  device> [UvDevice::new] GUID    = 1264-34211
[10:33:49.573]  device> [UvDevice::new] Using control endpoint 1, interface 0
[10:33:49.573]  device> [UvDevice::new] Using data endpoint 3, interface 2
[10:33:49.573]  device> Get genicam
[10:33:49.573]  cp> flags        = 0x4000
                     command      = read-memory-cmd
                     size         = 12
                     id           = 65301
                     address      = 0x0000000000000004
                     size         =         64 (0x00000040)
                     00000000 55 33 56 43 00 40 00 08 0c 00 15 ff 04 00 00 00  U3VC.@..........
                     00000010 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00                          ......@.
[10:33:49.606]  device> [UvDevice::read_memory] Try 1/5: command sending error: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
...
[10:33:49.917]  device> [UvDevice::_bootstrap] Error during memory read
```

At this point I no longer know what to do.
If ran from Ubuntu desktop, the issue is not present. So the issue seems WSL related, but that is just a guess.

1. use

```
(PS C:\Users\michal.dvorak> usbipd bind --force -b 2-3)
PS C:\Users\michal.dvorak> usbipd wsl attach -b 2-3
```

without forcing following warning is given

```
usbipd: warning: Unknown USB filter 'tdevflt' may be incompatible with this software; 'bind --force' may be required.
```

2. installed aravis-tools using apt
3. downloaded aravis-tools src and built it from scratch following [a guide](https://stackoverflow.com)
4. run the arv-viewer-0.8 with and without sudo.

Without sudo the camera doesn't appear. With sudo, it appears but cant be interacted with, with sudo and -d all:3 it gives the above posted error multiple times.